# How do I select and display data over several dates for comparison

Tags: mysql, date, select

I have a MySQL Table that captures details of attendance of church fellowship meetings in different locations . A District has 2 to 3 meeting locations; these meetings hold once a week. The important fields are

districtCode 
cellCode
meetingDate
males
females
children

I wish to display a table that shows the attendance over a period of a maximum of 4 meetings (4 different dates); such as http://www.oatogunde.com/tunde.html .

I am confused on how to construct the SELECT statement that will give me the desired result for a date range.

I 'd appreciate anyone's suggestions and help.

Thank you

Comment: It looks as though you need a crosstab query but I haven't got any good references for you. Try google mysql crosstab query.

Comment: It will not be easy (nor maintainable) to have *one* SQL requests returning the result as expected. Is some post-processing in the host program language acceptable? Anyway, please provide some actual test data test for your DB and the *expected* result. You might wish to publish those on http://sqlfiddle.com/ in order to ease experiment and obtain better answers

Comment: So  `date` isn't an important field?

Comment: the meetingDate is one of the columns.

Comment: Thank you fro your response. Some test data is on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e656/17247  . and sample of expected result is at http://www.oatogunde.com/tunde.html .